# sqlite запросы в Room

Tags: java, android, sql, select, room

В **DAO** у меня Query в которую мне бы нужно подставить запрос where из конструктора. **WHERE всегда разный**, но не пойму как подставить запрос целиком.

**value = "type = 'WRN' "**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOG + " WHERE :value "   + " ORDER BY id DESC")
Cursor select(String value);
```

т.е если я запрос выглядит вот так, то все работает:

**value = " 'WRN' "**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOG + " WHERE type = :value"   + " ORDER BY id DESC")
Cursor select(String value);
```

Можно сделать так, что бы я подставлял в поле where свое непредсказуемое условие целиком?

Comment: Ой, да, прошу прощения за невнимательность.

Comment: Должно работать как то так: `@Query("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOG + " WHERE " + value  + " ORDER BY id DESC")`, где value: String value = "type = WRN", но проверять мне лень и не на чем

Comment: вроде так нельзя

Comment: Нет, так нельзя к сожалению. value просто подсветит красным.

Comment: тогда, видимо, вместо аннотации нужно вызывать напрямую [метод query()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) этой библиотеки, там вы можете сформировать любую SQL-строку перед передачей в метод. Он вернет так же `Cursor` ,как и ваш метод select с аннотацией